# Is it possible to plant iris seeds in early spring?

Tags: seeds, germination, planting-times, irises

I've saved seeds from my irises from last spring with the intention of planting them. However, most of the guides I've read have suggested planting them in the autumn.

Is it possible to plant the seeds in the spring? If so, how should I go about this?

Notes: I live in the UK.

Comment: The reason they're planted in autumn outdoors (in a sunny spot) is because they need cold over winter to germinate - they usually appear in spring, though it depends on which variety of iris. Not sure what will happen if you plant them now, but they may not keep till next autumn

Comment: Can you refrigerate the seeds? This is one way to break winter dormancy. Most people either plant the seeds and then refrigerate or "plant" them in a self-seal/ziplock plastic bag.